# unix shell : create different tar files using a string in a array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, unix

We have services that generate files named with modules names. For ex., acqDou module generates

```
   acqDou_0001.out
   acqDou_08981.out
   acqDou_23423.out
```

The `acq_cheat` module generates files with almost same name, but last numbering is a bit diffrent.

My Requirment is to tar these files on the basis of module names, one tar file per module, such as `acqDou.tar` and `acq_cheat.tar`

Below is the programm I attmepted:

```
cd /home/swap/output/outfiles
for i in *; 
do
        j=`echo $i | grep -v 'out$'` 
        if [ -z $j ]; 
            then continue; 
        fi 
    count1=$(echo $i | tr -d -c '_' | wc -m)
    if [ $count1 -eq 2 ]
    then
        two=`ls -1 $i | cut -d'_' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 | uniq`
    else
        two=`ls -1 $i | cut -d'_' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f1 | uniq`
    fi
    _FILE="${_FILE} $two"
done
_FILE2=`echo "${_FILE[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '`
echo "${_FILE2}"
for m in "${_FILE2}"
do
  ls -lrt *${m}*.x
tar -cpf $m.tar /home/swap/output/outfiles/*${m}*
done
}
```

Comment: Please provide what you attempted so that you can get help in optimizing/fixing. This site is not for providing you with programs.

Comment: Fazlin, I have pasted the attempted code here. 
First loop will the keywords to search for the file name. It is also help full to name a tar file. 
Second loop is to attempt tar file. But, it is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Make tars for all possible module types present in the directory - in one shot.

lets say you have modules named as.. acqDou, acqDumb, acqcheat, acqfunny - In module_XXXX.out format.

something which may looks like this, as shown below. So i got 4 modules and 500 files of each of them in the directory. They all are empty, but it doesn't matter.

```
 >Wed Oct 05|01:15:13|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ls -lrtha *.out|head -7 ; echo ; ls -lrtha |tail -8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDou_0.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDumb_0.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqcheat_0.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqfunny_0.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDou_1.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDumb_1.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 0 Oct  5 00:58 acqcheat_1.out

-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDumb_498.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqcheat_498.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqfunny_498.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDou_499.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqDumb_499.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqcheat_499.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav    0 Oct  5 00:58 acqfunny_499.out
drwxrwxr-x. 2 gaurav gaurav  64K Oct  5 01:14 .
 >Wed Oct 05|01:15:30|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp %
```

In order to achieve the objective:

we can list the files, strip off the numbers (using sed), sort and unique the list (which gives the possible present module names in the directory) and then feed it to a while loop, to read module names one by one .. and then generate our output tarfile, module name wise and having files of that module only.

Here is the command:

```
ls *.out |sed 's/[0-9]//g'|sort|uniq|sed 's/_.out//g'|while read module
do 
    tar -cvf ${module}.tar ${module}*
done
```

We get something like this, once we finish.

```
 >Wed Oct 05|01:16:43|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ls -lrth *.tar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 260K Oct  5 01:16 acqcheat.tar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 260K Oct  5 01:16 acqDou.tar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 260K Oct  5 01:16 acqDumb.tar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 260K Oct  5 01:16 acqfunny.tar
 >Wed Oct 05|01:16:48|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp %
```

4 tar files have been created, with their module names. And it contains its respective module files. Let us see by using tar -tvf command. I will run it on all tar files and just take 2 lines as output, per file.

```
 >Wed Oct 05|01:18:29|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ls *.tar|while read file
 do 
     echo ;echo "Looking inside file: $file"
     tar -tvf $file|head -2
 done

Looking inside file: acqcheat.tar
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqcheat_0.out
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqcheat_100.out

Looking inside file: acqDou.tar
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqDou_0.out
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqDou_100.out

Looking inside file: acqDumb.tar
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqDumb_0.out
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqDumb_100.out

Looking inside file: acqfunny.tar
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqfunny_0.out
-rw-rw-r-- gaurav/gaurav     0 2016-10-05 00:58 acqfunny_100.out
 >Wed Oct 05|01:18:42|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp %
```

We do really have 500 files in each tar file. Let us just confirm that too.

```
 >Wed Oct 05|01:18:42|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp % ls *.tar|while read file
 do 
     echo ; echo "File count in tar file: $file"
     tar -tvf $file|wc -l
 done

File count in tar file: acqcheat.tar
500

File count in tar file: acqDou.tar
500

File count in tar file: acqDumb.tar
500

File count in tar file: acqfunny.tar
500
 >Wed Oct 05|01:20:03|gaurav@[STATION]:/root/ga/scripts/temp/tmp %
```

Cheers,
Gaurav

Comment: With some changes as my requirement. It worked. Thanks a Ton Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

In case you can distinguish the files by their name, the solution can be so simple straightforward:

```
tar cf acqDou.tar acqDou*.out*
tar cf acq_cheat.tar acq_cheat*.out*
```

If there are several such modules, you can even apply a simple for loop to process them:

```
for m in acqDou acq_cheat
  do
    tar cf $m.tar ${m}*.out*
done
```

Comment: I have a problem with this for loop. the filename is acqDou_12345.out.1
This tar syntax is not working here.

Comment: I see. Then you should set the mask so that it fits your filenames. Eg:tar cf $m.tar ${m}*.out*